# SQLite Database creation error in blackberry

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to create an SQLite DB using BlackBerry IDE. First I mount sdcard to a folder in my PC using simulator.

```
URI myURI = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/" + "Test.db");
d = DatabaseFactory.create(myURI);
d.close();
```

After I run the code I get the exception

> Path does not contains a proper root list. See FileSystemRegistry class for details

Anybody know what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below code without any changes please

```
Database d;
public CreateDatabaseScreen()
{

   try
   {
       URI myURI = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/my_database/" +"Test.db"); 
       d = DatabaseFactory.create(myURI);
       d.close();
       add(new RichTextField("DB created successfully"));
   }
   catch ( Exception e ) 
   {         
       System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
       e.printStackTrace();
       add(new RichTextField("Error: "+e.toString()));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for ur reply, i mounted a folder on "D" drive(D:/ABC) and do  URI myURI = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/" + "Test.db");
But same error.I gave full permission to ABC folder.

Comment: @vks: did you check in that folder, whether the db file is created or not

Comment: @vks: Hi.. can you try the above code without any changes for my sake please ?

Comment: Hi arun,I run the above code and get same error.I created a folder ABC on my d: drive and mount it using simulator.After mounting a blackberry folder created inside ABC.After that i run the above code , but got the error "Path does not contains a proper root list. See FileSystemRegistry class for details".I checked the folder after running the app, but no "Databases" folder found in side ABC folder.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a USB cable is inserted while you are testing the app. If this is the case just disconnect and try again. On BB if USB cable is attached then SDCard becomes unavailable.

Comment: @vks: Then I think smth other prevents your device (or simulator) from "seeing" its SDCard. Sometimes if you start debugging, then simulator may have not SDCard (because it is not configured to have in the debug mode). Can you check if there is an SDCard in your device/simulator? You can do this by opening Media BB application and use its filemanager to browse to the root of the filesystem - there you can see if there is an SDCard visible.